# Wait for variable number of events inside WaitForMultipleObjects windows

Tags: c++, events, synchronization, msdn, waitformultipleobjects

Usually, WaitForMultipleObjects takes an argument which tells it that for how many events this method need to wait.

```
DWORD WaitForMultipleObjects(
              DWORD        Count,
              const HANDLE *lpHandles,
              BOOL         bWaitAll,
              DWORD        dwMilliseconds
             );
```

my requirement is to wait for not a fixed number of events. So, it is possible to wait for a variable number of events in the above function or what is the other way through that I can achieve this in windows.

Comment: You can create the second parameter dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a container such as [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
#include <vector>
//...
int numHandles = 10;
std::vector<HANDLE> vHandles(numHandles);
//...
vHandles[0] = CreateThread(arguments);
vHandles[1] = CreateThread(arguments);
//... etc. 
WaitForMultipleObjects(vHandles.size(), vHandles.data(), TRUE, INFINITE);
```

Comment: And if you want it to return as soon as at least _one_ event is in a signalled state:  `WaitForMultipleObjects(vHandles.size(), vHandles.data(), FALSE, INFINITE);` - but be aware that if more than one event is signalled, it'll always return the one with the smallest index in the `vector`. Example: If the first event in the `vector` becomes signalled between every call to `WaitForMultipleObjects`, it will be the _only_ event you'll get in return. If that becomes a problem you can `std::swap` the handled event with `vHandles.back()` between calls.